# using IEnumerable<> as List<> when dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking at some very interesting code. I am trying to understand why it works.

The code in the controller is as follows.

```
var paymentInfo = controllerService.GetPaymentSummary();
ViewBag.PaymentInfo = paymentInfo;
```

In the controller service class there is this code.

```
public IEnumerable<SomeType> GetPaymentSummary()
{
    // ...
    return paymentInfo; // is of type List<SomeType>
}
```

And in the View, there is this very interesting code.

```
@if (ViewBag.PaymentInfo.Count > 0)
{
    // do something..
}
```

The View makes use of `Count` property which belongs to `List<T>`. How is this possible?

In the controller, for example, I cannot write `paymentInfo.Count` because `paymentInfo` is of type `IEnumerable<SomeType>`.

I understand that this has something to do with `ViewBag` being dynamic, but could someone elaborate please?

Comment: Well, you've pretty much said it yourself. `ViewBag` is `dynamic`, so expressions containing it tend not to have compile-time type checks. Instead, they are resolved dynamically (essentially via reflection) and thus they use the runtime type of the objects involved.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using reflection to get return type of `GetPaymentSummary()` and it is `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. I guess something else happens at runtime as it is seen differently?

Comment: The runtime of an object isn't the return type of the code that returned it. The runtime type is determined by what constructor was used to create that particualr object (at runtime). Thus, the runtime type is never an interface (such as `IEnumerable`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Think of it this way:

`IEnumerable` is just a contract, stating certain requirements that the return value from your method (that is `paymentInfo`) must have.

What `paymentInfo` actually *is*, is a `List`. Since `List` implements `IEnumerable`, it can also behave as and be treated as an `IEnumerable`, but it's runtime type is still `List`.

When using `Dynamic`, what is important is not the *specified* return type (`IEnumerable`), but the actual object; All that is checked is "*does this object contain a member `Count`?*", and since `List` has a `Count`, this works out fine.

Of course, if `GetPaymentSummary()` should change at some point, and return some other implementation of `IEnumerable` that does *not* contain a `Count` member, your code might break.

***Updated after feedback in a comment below:***

You can avoid that by using `.Any()` instead:

```
@if (ViewBag.PaymentInfo.Any() > 0) 
{
    // do something..
}
```

This should work fine since `.Any()` is declared in `IEnumerable`, and not just in `List`.

Comment: Instead you can use `@if (ViewBag.PaymentInfo.Any())`, which is part of `IEnumerable` and makes `.ToList` redundant

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for the feedback, that`s quite true! Updated my answer.